# Modelbinding returns null for object when property has invalid type

Tags: asp.net-core

I have `record` like this which I'm using in `Post` handler in ASP.NET Core (7.x):

```cs
public record Something(int? SomeProperty, int? AnotherProperty);
```

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> DoSomething([FromBody]Something something) {...}
```

If the client sends this JSON, the model binding silently fails and `something` is `null`.

```json
{
  "someProperty": "1",
  "anotherProperty": 2
}
```

Even if there's another property holding a valid value, the whole object `something` is `null`.

I would expect to just ignore the wrong properties and deserialize them as `null` but not the whole object.

Are there any serializer options I have to modify?

**Update**

```cs
.AddJsonOptions(
  options =>
    {
      options.JsonSerializerOptions.NumberHandling = 
        JsonNumberHandling.AllowReadingFromString;
    }
);
```

Source: [ASP.NET Core apps allow deserializing quoted numbers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/serialization/5.0/jsonserializer-allows-reading-numbers-as-strings)

Comment: I'm sorry, but is it possible that this is by design?

Answer (score 0):

You should set fields as nullable like this:

```
public record Something(int? SomeProperty, int? AnotherProperty);
```

Comment: Sorry, my mistake posting the question. Properties *are* nullable. Will fix the question.